# Cpufreq in non-root

Tags: python, linux

I want to change the frequency of a CPU, but the files in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq are only writable by root, and i would prefer to do something common users have permission to access. What would be the best way (possibly freedesktop friendly) to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with my problem. It's for processes and such.